# ADO.net Modeling Question

Tags: ado.net

I have built my database design and diagram. Now i want to build a ADO.net model of that design. Now my question is that, should i build a model of the the whole design?(Since the design is not so big) or create several models for convenience? Which is better?

> I have Student, Teacher, Course, .... tables

Should i make studentModel, TeacherModel.... or make only a ExamSystemModel of all the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a small model, you may get away with a single DataSet.

I have built models based on tasks and processes. I may build a DataSet with everything I need to register for a class, another one with everything needed to grade tests, etc.

I have built DataSets for single tables.

I have read data from DataReaders directly into entity objects.

Etc...

The architecture of the rest of the application will determine how you build your ADO.NET model. What are you trying to do with your system? How will it be used? Pick an architecture and build an appropriate model.